# Android Emulator (AVD) on DigitalOcean (etc.)

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualization, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

Is it possible to install Android SDK and Emulator on some VPS (digitalocean, google cloud, amazon aws etc.) then run some emulated phone on it and connect to it from any remote PC (using some VNC or another remote access software)? As a result - I can have access to some virtual phone from any point of the world?

I need to open specific apps that are available only on Android phones, but I don't want to run it on my own computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Genymotion Cloud Image for AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MREUQPU

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is running test or building packages at cloud, I think you can do it, firstly you should install android sdk with required versions, after that you need to create the headless emulator.

For example if you decided to run the tests on amazon ec2, you can follow two steps

Firstly install android sdk from the command line:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk
ANDROID_VERSION=26 
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=26.0.2

mkdir $ANDROID_HOME .android \
    && cd $ANDROID_HOME \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

To create the headless emulator, you can follow the instruction [from](https://paulemtz.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-testing-in-headless-emulator.html)

Comment: I need to open specific apps that are available only on Android phones, but I don't want to run it on my own computer.

Comment: @iwex Do you want to see that app's gui ?

Comment: @iwex I think you can do it, If you can find a solution for to do, please let me  know